# Clarifications on the Domo dashboard

Tags: domo

The tool I'm using to develop a dashboard is Domo Centerview builder. The graphs are not getting loaded when I open the dashboard but it appears only after selecting the controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controls like check-box, radio-buttons , radio-group and drop down lists should be placed independently. It should not come under any KPI's if u place it inside any KPI's it wont take the data until some event happens in the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about [Domo](http://www.domo.com) here - which is used to build business intelligence dashboards.

Any graph you create using the analyzer goes to your overview page. You can then move the graphs/cards to the page that you want.